# Error with Chrome Extension sending message from background to content script

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, service-worker, sendmessage, content-script

I'm learning about Chrome Extensions and I want to send a message from the background to a content script. I'm trying to do the simplest example, but I keep getting the following error:

> Error in event handler: TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined
> (reading 'id')
> at sendMessageBackgroundToScript (chrome-extension://ibghimmhcpdahopejafegpkgfcijmcin/event.js:4:35)

This is the code:

manifest.json:

```
{
    "name": "Send Messages",
    "description": "An example of how to send messages from background to script",
    "version": "1.0",
    "manifest_version": 3,
    "background": {
        "service_worker": "event.js"
    },
    "action": {
        "default_title": "Send Message",
        "default_icon": "images/icon32.png"
    },
    "permissions": [
        "scripting"
    ],
    "content_scripts": [
        {
            "matches": ["<all_urls>"],
            "js": ["script.js"]
        }
    ]

}
```

event.js:

```
chrome.action.onClicked.addListener(sendMessageBackgroundToScript);

function sendMessageBackgroundToScript(tabs) {
  chrome.tabs.sendMessage(tabs[0].id, {text: "This is a message"})
}
```

script.js:

```
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(gotMessage);

function gotMessage(message, sender, sendResponse) {
  console.log(message.text);
}
```

Comment: See the documentation for onClicked: it receives a single `tab` object, not an array.

Comment: Thank you very much, I changed the argument to tab and it worked. In the real project I need the event to be triggered by an alarm, not sure if it will work there, but this is a step forward. Thanks a lot!!!

Comment: I copy pasted the codes and removed the [0] nut I get the following error: "Uncaught (in promise) Error: Could not establish connection. Receiving end does not exist."

Any idea why?